# Recommended XMP tag for "Scanner"

Tags: metadata, xmp

What XMP tag should I use to store information about the scanner that was used to scan the print?

I don't see anything in the recommended dc, xmp, iptcCore and iptcExt schemas:

http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: there isn't one. I suggest using this custom schema: http://analogexif.sourceforge.net/help/analogexif-xmp.php, because at least you will be consistent with what *someone* is doing (and enough people doing that is the genesis of many standards).

Specifically, the relevant tags are:

> **ScannerMaker (Xmp.AnalogExif.ScannerMaker)**
>
> String value. Scanner manufacturer, for example *Epson*.
>
> **Scanner (Xmp.AnalogExif.Scanner)**
>
> String value. Scanner model including manufacturer, for example *Epson Perfection 4490 Photo*.
>
> **ScannerSoftware (Xmp.AnalogExif.ScannerSoftware)**
>
> String value. Scanner software, for example *Silverfast*.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, and as a bonus their schema defines XMP for film information, which is better than the homebrew tags I was going to use.